# Enforcing a max limit on the count of a given process

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, locking, semaphore

I've a user process say `user_proc` which can be invoked by multiple users in linux OS.

How do I restrict that any given point of time, the total number of instances of `user-proc` shouldn't exceed a given max_user_proc_count.

For example, if 10 users try to run `user_proc` at the same time then total number of instances of `user_proc` will be 10. But I want to restrict total number of instances not to exceed beyond a thresold(say 5). So if 10 users try to run at the same time then it will run only 5 instances and then it will wait for already running `user_proc` to complete. Moment 1 `user_proc` completes running then 6th instance will be started. If 2 `user_proc` completes then 7th and 8th instances will be started.

Why I want to achieve this is I've seen `user_proc`hogs the CPU so I wanted to put a cap on the total instances of `user_proc`.

Also I am invoking the `user_proc` from a python program so if I can achieve this from a python program then it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hard enforcement through [cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt) namely with [process number controller](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/pids.rst) but that would stop processes from being launched.

To achieve what you wish I think you'd have to go with a queue that would allow processes to be run. You can do it in your python project by communicating with a central process that would make it wait until a slot is available.

Comment: How do I maintain a global level queue which can be accessed by all Linux users? Maybe I can use locking when reading and updating the queue to avoid race conditions but the bigger question is how do I implement a global level queue?

Comment: Now that I think about it better, you don't even need a global queue, a named semaphore should be enough for this purpose.